# Getting Current Location using only GPS in Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova

I use the geolocation plugin in Cordova 3.5. And I have coded as follow:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
    alert("lat : "+lat+" lng : " +lng");
});
```

I am wandering whether this code can work to get lat lng without Internet connection and GPS on. If not, is there any solution to do so? Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without Internet connection, there are still sources like Cell ID's, RFID and MAC addresses of devices you are connected to (e. g. WIFI routers, Bluetooth)

The code should work, but you can add a few things (Eventlistener and error alert in case that the position cannot be found):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        }

    function onSuccess(pos) {
            var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
            var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
            alert("lat : " + lat + " lng : " + lng);

        }

    function onError(error) {
            alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
```

I know that for example the Google location API uses a cache for the latest known location, which can be read out anytime.
I am not sure if Cordova also uses something similar but it could be.

Comment: It is still in doubt. I test with two different devices and it works without Internet Connection. but I am not sure whether google location API uses a cache to get the late location and display it. One more thing there is no gps icon appear on the status bar.

Comment: Actually the location that I got during offline mode is the last location that i once got when I am online. Any solution to fix this. I want to get location during offline. thx for your help.

Comment: You have a typo in your onSuccess method.  The argument should be pos not position.

Answer (score 2):

check if geolocation is properly installed or not

restart your phone (silly solution but it works sometimes.I faced it once)

check if your geo permissions & settings are turned on in device

test with this code

```
options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

If you're using android, try to get the error with eclipse logcat.

On iOS this will always work one way or the other. If the plugin fails, the browser's own Geolocation API will be used. There's some undesired side effects with the fallback though:

The permission dialog that pop's up has the html file's name in the title instead of the app name
Granted permissions will only persist as long as the app is running
On Android it only works if you have set the correct permissions in app/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Answer (score 2):

As @jcesarmobile pointed out here [Cordova geolocation plugin not getting location from GPS for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646690/cordova-geolocation-plugin-not-getting-location-from-gps-for-android/29647031#29647031):

> They are using HTML5 geolocation implementation instead of native
>   code. They removed the android java code on release 0.3.7 of the
>   plugin

```
### 0.3.7 (Apr 17, 2014)
* CB-6422: [windows8] use cordova/exec/proxy
* CB-6212: [iOS] fix warnings compiled under arm64 64-bit
* CB-5977: [android] Removing the Android Geolocation Code.  Mission Accomplished.
* CB-6460: Update license headers
* Add NOTICE file
```

Hope this helps